# Extracting the coordinate of a particular point of interest from a ListPlot

Tags: plotting, interactive, tooltip

Is there a way to obtain the coordinate of a point of interest in a `ListPlot`?

As an example, I have a list containing many sets of 2D coordinates and the plot drawn is discontinuous at one point (the first derivative is not continuous and the gradient increases suddenly).

Can I extract the location of that point interactively? Otherwise, I have to search through the list of data myself to determine the change of gradient, which defeats the whole purpose of drawing a plot. Also, using the Get Coordinates function from the right click menu does not give very accurate results.

Answer (score 22, accepted):

#### `ListPlot` accepts data wrappers besides `Tooltip`

(although I could not find any mention of this feature in the docs).

So, @Jens' method can be achieved without post-processing:

```
 data = Table[{Sin[n], Sin[2 n]}, {n, 50}];
 ListPlot[PopupWindow[Tooltip[#], #] & /@ data]
```

[image]

On mouseover:

[image]

Click on a point:

[image]

Note: Thought this was a new feature added in Version-9, but as @Alexey Popkov noted it also works in version 8.0.4, so it has been around for some time.

**Update:** A simpler version of @Mr.Wizard's `printTip` can also be used as a wrapper directly inside `ListPlot`:

```
 ListPlot[Button[Tooltip@#, Print[#]] & /@ N@data]
```

[image]

**Update 2:** Collecting point coordinates:

```
 clicks = {};
 Column[{ListPlot[Button[Tooltip@#, AppendTo[clicks, #]] & /@ N@data,
   ImageSize -> 300],
  "\n\t", Row[{"clicks = " , Dynamic[clicks // TableForm]}]}]
```

[image]

Comment: +1. It works in v.8.0.4 too.

Comment: @Alexey, thanks for the vote. Perhaps, I should edit to remove the reference to version 9.

Comment: I had no idea this would work, from v7 no less. +1!

Comment: Although the `Print` method doesn't work in version 7: it prints to the Messages window which is why I had to resort to `NotebookWrite`.

Comment: @Mr.Wizard I tested the `Button` function into `DateListPlot` instead of `ListPlot` and don't work. Some clue? `Tooltip` worked nice.

Comment: @Murta We're in undocumented territory here.  The replacement rule (`/.`) methods should still work.

Comment: @Murta, I tried several `--Plot` funtions; this seems to work only with `ListPlot`.

Comment: @kguler, I converted my `DateListPlot` into a `ListPlot`. Not so nice, but worked :) tks

Comment: I can't make your method work for anything but simple `ListPlot` with one data set. Try it with two sets, as in `{data1, data2}` and it doesn't seem to produce anything useful.

Comment: @Jens, both `PopupWindow` and `Button` work fine with `ListPlot` with multiple data sets, provided you add the extra layer of `Map` to push the wrapper to the level of individual data elements. Try, for example, `ListPlot[Button[Tooltip@#, Print[#]] & /@ # & /@ {N@data1, N@data2}]` or `ListPlot[PopupWindow[Tooltip@#, #] & /@ # & /@ {N@data1, N@data2}]` (Windows Vista 64b, version 9; haven't checked if it works the same way in version 8.0.4)

Comment: Yes, that works, but I like my own approach better. With your solution you have to use `Map` in different ways depending on the plot argument, whereas my rule works equally in all cases, without requiring `Map` at all (instead leveraging the internal mapping done by `Tooltip`).

Comment: I was mislead by the title of your answer. It suggests that it should be possible to replace `Tooltip` by `PopupWindow[Tooltip@#, #]&` in the standard command `ListPlot[Tooltip[{data1, data2}]]`. But that does *not* work. So maybe you should change the bold-face title because you're not really using a wrapper around all the data, as one would expect for `Tooltip`.

Comment: @Jens, I too like your approach better.  Regarding "suggests that it should be possible to replace ...": please note that  the wrappers are `Map`ped (`.../@`) to data even with a single data set. And, regarding  "... not really using a wrapper around all the data":  correct, but this is never claimed/implied anywhere in my post... Besides,  wrappers can be "on individual data, datasets or collection of datasets" and not all wrappers are used "as one would expect for `Tooltip`".

Comment: @kguler - referring to the bit from update 2, would it be possible to add a checkbox to chose to add or remove the point from the list? or perhaps maybe right-click to remove? sorry for asking so much, but I thought it would be useful for many people seeing this question.

Answer (score 12):

The answer by Mr. Wizard covers the built-in options, but one thing that you may be missing is that the tooltip alone isn't very convenient when it comes to *recording* the desired coordinates for later use. You'd have to read off the numbers and type them in again.

If you want to automate this process too, then you might be interested in the following:

```
data = Table[{Cos[n], Cos[2 n]}, {n, 50}];
ListPlot[Tooltip[data]] /. 
 Tooltip[x__] :> PopupWindow[Tooltip[x], Last[{x}]]
```

Here I appended a replacement rule to the `ListPlot` that attaches a `PopupWindow` to every single instance of a `Tooltip` that is found in the graphic. Since a separate `Tooltip` automatically wraps each generated point in the plot, we will now also get a `PopupWindow` for every point. The contents of the window is set to be the same as the tool tip content:

[image: popupwindow]

The window pops up when you click on the point of interest. From this window, you can textually copy the desired coordinate.

By the way, I put together a list of other coordinate-picking options [here](http://pages.uoregon.edu/noeckel/MathematicaGraphics.html#MousePosition) quite some time ago.

**Edit**

To make this post-processing really easy, just define a rule:

```
toolRule = Tooltip[x__] :> PopupWindow[Tooltip[x], Last[{x}]];
```

and apply it to any plot with `Tooltip`s as

```
ListPlot[Tooltip[...]]/.toolRule
```

It's important to remember that `ListPlot` accepts lists of lists as argument, in order to plot separate point sets. My method works *without change* for that case, e.g., try

```
data2 = Table[{Cos[n], Cos[2 n]}, {n, 50}];
ListPlot[Tooltip[{data, data2}]] /. toolRule
```

In fact, it works for any expression containing `Tooltip`s.

**Edit 2**

This solution is more robust than the one by kguler which relies on an undocumented feature apparently present only in `ListPlot`, which moreover has to be applied in different ways depending on the structure of the plot argument.

To illustrate the robustness, take a completely different example:

```
ContourPlot[
  1/(1 + Cos[x - 1]^20) - 1/(1 + Cos[(y - 1)^2 + x^2]^20), {x, -2, 
   2}, {y, -2, 2}, ColorFunction -> ColorData["Rainbow"], 
  Contours -> {-.25, -.31, -.15, .1, .28, .38, .45}, 
  PlotPoints -> 80] /. toolRule
```

[image: contour plot]

Without making any changes to my answer *whatsoever*, I can use it to copy the contour values in this `ContourPlot` exactly the same way I did for the coordinates in the `ListPlot`, again leveraging the built-in `Tooltip` mapping done behind the scenes.

**Edit 3: accumulating clicked points on the clipboard**

I thought of another interesting extension of the above rule-based post-processing:

Click any number of points with a `Tooltip`, and get their coordinates as a list on the clipboard.

Here's how that can be done. The rule is defined first, then I show an example (you can change the *name* of the rule to something more cool, I was just... fooling around):

```
toolSpoolRule = Tooltip[t__] :> Button[Tooltip[t], CopyToClipboard[
     First@
      Append[Cases[NotebookGet[ClipboardNotebook[]], 
        TooltipBox[x_, "\"Clicked Points\"", ___] :> 
         Tooltip[Append[ToExpression[x], Last[{t}]], 
          "Clicked Points"], Infinity],
       Tooltip[{Last[{t}]}, "Clicked Points"]]
     ]];

ListPlot[Tooltip@
   Evaluate[
    Table[N@Table[
       p + Exp[-t/10] {Cos[t], Sin[t]}/2, {t, 0, 10, .5}], {p, {{.5, 
        0}, {1, 0}}}]], Joined -> True, 
  PlotMarkers -> Automatic] /. toolSpoolRule
```

[image: spirals]

Now click a bunch of points - nothing visible happens, except that the contents of your clipboard is silently growing. When you're done, press the `paste` keys, and you'll get something like this:

> `{{0.530442,0.429276},{0.329644,0.372235},{0.188034,0.233045},{1.5,0.}}`

This gives you the freedom to insert the data you just collected at a location of your choosing.

Clearly this rule definition is more complex, but one nice thing about all these rules is that you define them only once. Then at a later point, you can apply them to any *existing* plots you may already have (as long as they use `Tooltip`), and make them interactive. The ability to do this without having to regenerate the plot can be quite useful if it takes a lot of computation to do so. And if you want popup windows instead of clipboard storage, just change the rule back to `toolRule`.

Comment: That's pretty slick. +1

Comment: @Mr.Wizard Thanks - and this works for  `Tooltip`s in all sorts of scenarios.

Comment: A bit shorter: `ListPlot[Tooltip @ data] /. Tooltip :> (Tooltip@## ~PopupWindow~ #2 &)`

Comment: @Mr.Wizard Ah yes, your favorite notation.

Answer (score 9):

Inspired by Jens' answer, here is a method that will print below the plot the coordinates of each point clicked.

```
printTip = Button[Tooltip@##, 
     SelectionMove[ButtonNotebook[], After, Cell]; 
     NotebookWrite[ButtonNotebook[], ToBoxes@#2], 
     Appearance -> "Frameless"] &;

data = N @ Table[{Sin[n], Sin[2 n]}, {n, 50}];

ListPlot[Tooltip @ data] /. Tooltip -> printTip
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

---

Sure.  There are a few ways to do this.  You can use `Tooltip`:

```
ListPlot[Tooltip @ data]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

Or you can use the [Get Coordinates tool](http://reference.wolfram.com/mathematica/howto/GetCoordinatesForPointsInAPlot.html) by right-clicking the graphic:

```
ListPlot @ data
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

When using this tool you will see a continuous coordinate tooltip, but you can also click (repeatedly) to mark points, then use <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>C</kbd> and <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>V</kbd> (Windows) to copy and paste these coordinates.

Comment: Thanks ToolTip is just what I want.