# EventHandler not working within DateListPlot (?)

Tags: graphics, eventhandler

I have some `{date, value}` data:

```
data = Transpose[{AbsoluteTime /@ Thread[{2012, Range[12], 15}], 
   RandomInteger[10, 12]}]
```

Normally I do initial tests with `DateListPlot` and then implement with `ListPlot` or `ListLinePlot` for efficiency. However I just tried this:

```
DateListPlot[
 Table[With[{i = i},
   EventHandler[data[[i]], "MouseClicked" :> {Print["hello"]}]], {i, 
   12}]
 ]
```

and got this error message

`DateListPlot::dtvals: Unable to automatically determine horizontal coordinates for the given data and DataRange.`

[image]

Whereas if I switch to `ListPlot` or `ListLinePlot` it works fine:

```
ListPlot[
 Table[With[{i = i},
   EventHandler[data[[i]], 
    "MouseClicked" :> {Print["hello " <> ToString[i]]}]], {i, 12}]
 ]
```

[image]

Can anyone explain why `EventHandler` would not work within `DateListPlot` (hopefully this is not a RTFM question!)?

Problem exists with 8.0.4 and 9.0.1 on Mac 10.6.8

Comment: `Tooltip` seems to be only wrapper that works with `DateListPlot`. `EventHandler`,`Button`, `PopupWindow` ... work with `ListPlot` but not with `DateListPlot`. A workaround is to postprocess to replace `Tooltip` with a wrapper of your choice as in Jens' answer in [this Q/A](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/16927/125): `DateListPlot[Table[With[{i = i}, Tooltip[data[[i]]]], {i, 12}]] /. Tooltip[x_, ___] :> EventHandler[x, "MouseClicked" :> {Print["hello"]}]`

Comment: @kguler I prefer to use `ListPlot` anyway because `DateListPlot` is so slow (presumably due to slow date and time functions that are called). So a workaround is unnecessary -- i.e. I'll prototype with `ListPlot` as well as deploy with it. Was just wondering if what I observed is known and if so whether it is by design or a bug.

Comment: I have the same issues with `DateListPlot` on Windows (both mma versions 8.0.4 and 9.0).

Comment: @kguler you mean same issues with slowness or with `EvetnHandler`?

Comment: slowness mostly.

Comment: @kguler `ListLinePlot` can be up to an order of magnitude faster, incl. time for absolute time conversion. The catch is you have to make a tick function but small price to pay. For dynamic plots it can be the difference between acceptable and unacceptable updating. Obviously way more overhead in `DateListPlot`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The objective of the question was to clarify whether `EventHandler` should work with `DateListPlot` (work arounds were not sought).

Wolfram tech support confirmed that `EventHandler` does not work with `DateListPlot`. This is not a bug it is just that this capability is not available for `DateListPlot`.

Comment: Now that you have explained things in terms simple enough for me to understand, I have deleted my misguided attempt to record an answer. I am pleased, though, that the question is now has an answer.

Comment: Mike, why not accept this as a conclusion (as there is no real solution) terminating the issue at hand?

Comment: ok. I guess it closes it off.