# A simple ListPlot with different colours and a Tooltip

Tags: plotting

I know that the  threads [ListPlot with each point a different color and a legend bar](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/1300/listplot-with-each-point-a-different-color-and-a-legend-bar) and [Extracting the coordinate of a particular point of interest from a ListPlot](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/16925/extracting-the-coordinate-of-a-particular-point-of-interest-from-a-listplot) are somehow the answers to my questions but I am having a hard time understanding them when trying to apply them to the following problem:

```
ListPlot[{{0,1},{0,0},{1,0},{1,1},{0.5,0.2}},
   PlotStyle->Directive[PointSize[Large]]]
```

The x-coordinate of the first four points won't change; only the y-coordinate will. {0,1} and {1,0} must have the same color;  {0,0} and {1,1} must have the same colour but different from the first case and {0.5,0.2} a different color when compared to the other two cases. The resulting plot must also have the value of the y-coordinate for each point shown all the time (no need to click a mouse or the like).

I believe that the solution should be self-contained within `ListPlot` since I am planning to use it inside a `Manipulate` with other plots.

Comment: not so clear to understand the question. make 5 points three different colors?

Comment: Yes. The first and the fourth have the same colour;  the second and third point have the same colour but different from the previous set of points and finally the fifth point has a different colour when compared to the other two set of points.

Comment: What's the role of Tooltip? another question is whether the 5 points generated by some pattern or just this case. My first thought is split 5-points list to 3 sublists, but if could be split by hand is much easier. If with some pattern, should,,,

Answer (score 2):

You can split the list of points into sublists and apply a different style for each sublist using PlotStyle.

For the labeling, I have not found any ListPlot option capable of this, but you can render labels manually with Epilog and Text:

```
data = {{{0, 1}, {1, 0}}, {{0, 0}, {1, 1}}, {{0.5, 0.2}}};

ListPlot[data,
  PlotStyle -> {Directive[Red,PointSize[Large]], Blue, Gray},
  Epilog -> Map[Text[Round[Last@#, .1], # + .05] &, data, {Depth@data-2}]]
```

Comments and explanations:

- Text is Mapped at level "Depth of data -2", so it will be compatible with lists of different depths.
- By doing so, {x,y} is fed to the Text pure function, so Last@# yields the y value.
- Replace Round[, .1] by any formatting function you like (e.g. NumberForm).
- I have used # + .05 as the coordinate, so the label for the point {0,1} will be placed at {0.05, 1.05}. You might want to change this according to your plot and point size and use different values for x and y translation using +{x,y}.

Comment: seems he need something tooltip?

Comment: I know he wrote tooltip, but then: "The resulting ListPlot must also have the value of the y-coordinate for each point showed all the time." ... sounded more like a static label to me?

Comment: First of all, many thanks. Yes, it sounds like a static label.  When I added PlotRange-> {{-0.5,1.5},{-0.5,1.5}} to see the labels, the size of the points have changed. Is that right?   One final question - How can this solution be used inside Manipulate (y-values will change according to some rule) where only the plot is shown?

Comment: Hm, the point size does not change with PlotRange. To play with the point size, have a look at `PointSize` and `AbsolutePointSize` in the documentation.

You can use something like:
`Manipulate[With[{data = {{0,1}, {1,manipulated+4}}}, (* -- your plot code here -- *)], {manipulated,0,10}]`

Answer (score 1):

Not so clear about tooltip and something else.

```
list={{0,1},{0,0},{1,0},{1,1},{0.5,0.2}}
listNew=(GatherBy[Most@list,OddQ[Position[list,#]]&])//Append[#,{Last@list}]&
ListPlot[listNew,PlotStyle->Directive[PointSize@Large]]
```

how to generate the sublists depend on the some patterns.

```
listNew=Partition[Permute[list,AlternatingGroup[3]]//Last,2,2,1,{}]
```

[image]

Comment: Many thanks.   Adding Epilog as shown on the other does the job.