# Manipulate: ListPlot and Labeling

Tags: manipulate

I am trying to make a set of scatterplots where the 'u' value is a year. I am using the following dataset:

```
DataPoints = {{{39, 34}, {58, 72}, {55, 71}, {61, 42}, {56, 60}, {23, 
    83}, {57, 70}, {54, 72}, {23, 80}, {20, 36}, {28, 64}, {25, 
    21}, {24, 90}, {57, 79}, {22, 65}, {53, 52}, {19, 74}, {63, 
    48}}, {{66, 59}, {62, 63}, {66, 37}, {65, 25}, {87, 78}, {61, 
    34}, {17, 27}, {55, 46}, {61, 38}, {70, 70}}, {{59, 43}, {55, 
    45}, {18, 16}, {29, 37}, {43, 30}, {62, 58}}, {{48, 59}, {14, 
    42}, {61, 39}, {55, 38}, {13, 38}, {17, 42}, {15, 27}, {58, 
    62}, {30, 46}, {54, 41}, {44, 23}, {53, 55}}}
Countries = {{"ARG", "CAN", "CZE", "FRA", "GER", "GHA", "ITA", "JPN", 
   "KEN", "LBN", "MEX", "PAK", "PHL", "POL", "ZAF", "KOR", "UGA", 
   "GBR"}, {"AUS", "CAN", "FRA", "GER", "ISR", "ITA", "LBN", "KOR", 
   "ESP", "GBR"}, {"FRA", "GER", "PAK", "RUS", "TUR", "GBR"}, {"CAN", 
   "CHN", "FRA", "GER", "IDN", "LBN", "PAK", "POL", "RUS", "ESP", 
   "TUR", "GBR"}}
```

I am using the following to do this:

```
Manipulate[
 Show[ListPlot[DataPoints[[year]]], 
  PlotRange -> {{0, 100}, {0, 100}}, AxesOrigin -> {0, 0}, 
  AxesLabel -> {"X", "Y"}], {{year,1}, {1 ->  "2002", 2 -> "2003", 3 -> "2004", 
   4 -> "2005"}}]
```

Is there a way to label each datapoint on the scatterplot with a Manipulate function? I can get it to work for one year only...

Thanks,
Arebearit

Note: Edited because first problem was solved.

Comment: Welcome to Mathematica.SE! I suggest that: 1) You take the introductory [Tour](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/tour) now! 2) When you see good questions and answers, vote them up by [clicking the gray triangles](http://tinyurl.com/ch98nrh), because the credibility of the system is based on the reputation gained by users sharing their knowledge. Also, please remember to accept the answer, if any, that solves your problem, [by clicking the checkmark sign](http://tinyurl.com/4srwe2t)! 3) As you receive help, try to give it too, by answering questions in your area of expertise.

Comment: You mention an error message.  I see none when running your code on V 10.

Comment: Sorry about that, I just found the error and edited it out but forgot to remove my mention of it.

Comment: What sort of a label (content, etc.) do you wish for each point?  `ToolTip` accommodates labels when the mouse hovers over a point.  Is that useful?

Comment: Hello arebearit, what do you mean with "label each datapoint on a scatterplot..?"

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`ListPlot` accepts data sets with wrappers such as `Tooltip`, `Labeled`, ... , `Button` etc. (See [this answer](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/16929/125) on various wrappers you can use with `ListPlot`.)

Assuming that the label you want to attach to a point in `dataPoints` is the country label in the same position in `countries`, you can pre-process `dataPoints` and `countries` using `Labeled` to produce a  labeled data set.

```
labeleddata=Thread[Labeled[First@# ,Last@#]]&/@Transpose[{dataPoints,countries}];

Manipulate[Show[ListPlot[labeleddata[[year]]], 
  PlotRange -> {{0, 100}, {0, 100}}, AxesOrigin -> {0, 0}, AxesLabel -> {"X", "Y"}], 
  {{year,1}, {1 ->  "2002", 2 -> "2003", 3 -> "2004",  4 -> "2005"}}]
```

[image]

Comment: very nice.  Could you add a brief explanation of why it works?  Thanks.

Comment: Thank you @bbgodfrey. I will add some notes in a few minutes.

Comment: Thank you.  I could not find this capability in the ListPlot documentation.  Is it undocumented, or located somewhere else in the copious Mathematica documentation?  If undocumented, how did you discover it in the first place?

Comment: @bbgodfrey, as of v9, these features were undocumented; v10 `ListPlot` documentation does not mention them either. How I discovered was by trial/luck based on the hunch: _if `Tooltip` works, maybe so would other wrappers ..._

Comment: What a fantastic find @kguler! Thank you so much for this!

Comment: @arebearit, my pleasure. Welcome to mma.se.