# How to get exact coordinate of a point from a plot?

Tags: plotting, functions

I am using `BodePlot[]` to plot the magnitude and phase of a function as below.

```
BodePlot[1000/((1 + s/10^3)*(1 + s/10^6))]
```

After plotting the function, is there a way to get the exact coordinate of a point from the plot?
I tried to use <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>D</kbd> and the tool get coordinate but it doesn't return the exact coordinate at all.

Comment: related q/a: [Extracting the coordinate of a particular point of interest from a ListPlot](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/16925/125)

Comment: In what way does the **Get Coordinates** tool fail to do what you want?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

> [Is there a way to get coordinate of just a particular point?](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/115631/how-to-get-exact-coordinate-of-a-point-from-a-plot#comment313840_115633)

You can convert `Line` into the corresponding set of `Point`s each of which will be a `Button` which `Print`s the coordinates of that `Point` when you click on it (try this!):

```
plot = BodePlot[1000/((1 + s/10^3)*(1 + s/10^6))];
plot /. Line[pts_] :> Map[Button[Point[#], Print[#]] &, pts, {-2}]
```

> [image: plot]

Or (as [Michael E2](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/users/4999/michael-e2) suggests) you can copy the coordinates of the `Point` into the clipboard instead of `Print`ing:

```
plot /. Line[pts_] :> Map[Button[Point[#], CopyToClipboard[#]] &, pts, {-2}]
```

You can elegantly get the advantages of the both above approaches using (new in version 10.3) [`Echo`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Echo.html) as suggested by [J. M.](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/users/50/j-m):

```
plot /. Line[pts_] :> Map[Button[Point[#], CopyToClipboard[Echo[#]]] &, pts, {-2}]
```

Another alternative is to use `PopupWindow`:

```
plot /. Line[pts_] :> Map[PopupWindow[Point[#], #] &, pts, {-2}]
```

---

If you like the `CopyToClipboard` approach but you don't wish to print anything or display any popup windows, you still can get moderate control on which `Point` you have actually hit by the mouse via changing color and size of the `Point` when your cursor is over it. Increasing size of the `Point` reduces the possibility that this point will be accidentally de-selected as a result of unintended minor movement of the mouse cursor during the process of pressing of the mouse button:

```
plot /. Line[pts_] :> 
  Map[Button[Mouseover[Point[#], {Red, PointSize[Large], Point[#]}], 
     CopyToClipboard[#]] &, pts, {-2}]
```

I've added this notice because AFAIK currently there is no simple way to harmonize what you have first *selected* and then *clicked* by mouse in an unambiguous way (these events obviously are independent from each other).

Comment: You made Up a cool Point, +1

Comment: Or perhaps `CopyToClipboard[]` instead of `Print[]`.

Comment: Probably one can combine `CopyToClipboard[]` with `Echo[]` so that it both gets printed and copied.

Answer (score 4):

Using `Cases[]`

```
plot = BodePlot[1000/((1 + s/10^3)*(1 + s/10^6))]
Cases[plot, Line[x___] :> x, Infinity]

(*two group of data*)
```

Comment: Thank you. It seems to be complicated. Is there a way to get coordinate of just a particular point? I tried the one above but it returns only x from 1.69 to 7.3.

Answer (score 4):

```
bp[s_] := 1000/((1 + s/10^3)*(1 + s/10^6))

mybp = BodePlot[bp[s]]
```

[image]

Have a look at

[Short](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Short.html)

[Cases](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Cases.html)

```
Short[Cases[Normal@mybp, Line[s_] :> s, Infinity], 25]
```

> `{{{1.69897,59.9892},{1.70069,59.9891},{1.70241,59.989},{1.70584,59.9888},{1.71272,59.9884},{1.72646,59.9877},{1.72818,59.9876},{1.7299,59.9875},{1.73333,59.9873},{1.74021,59.9869},{1.75395,59.986},{1.75567,59.9859},{1.75739,59.9858},{1.76082,59.9856},{1.7677,59.9851},{1.78144,59.9842},{1.80893,59.982},{1.81079,59.9819},{1.81266,59.9817},{1.81638,59.9814},<<196>>,{7.18567,-47.4451},{7.19336,-47.7521},{7.20874,-48.3662},{7.2395,-49.5945},{7.24143,-49.6713},{7.24335,-49.7481},{7.24719,-49.9017},{7.25489,-50.2088},{7.27027,-50.8232},{7.27219,-50.9},{7.27411,-50.9768},{7.27796,-51.1304},{7.28565,-51.4376},{7.28757,-51.5144},{7.28949,-51.5912},{7.29334,-51.7448},{7.29526,-51.8216},{7.29718,-51.8984},{7.29911,-51.9752},{7.30103,-52.052}},{<<1>>,<<327>>,{<<18>>,-<<18>>}}}`

```
bp[s]
```

$\frac{1000}{\left(\frac{s}{1000000}+1\right) \left(\frac{s}{1000}+1\right)}$

```
bp[10] // N
```

> `990.089`

```
BodePlot[bp[s], {100, 222}]
```

[image]

See [Tooltip](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Tooltip.html)

```
BodePlot[{Tooltip[bp[s]]}, ImageSize -> 550, Frame -> True, 
PlotStyle -> {Directive[Thick, ColorData[20, 1]], 
Directive[Thick, ColorData[20, 9]]}, Frame -> False, 
AspectRatio -> 1/2.25, GridLines -> Automatic, 
GridLinesStyle -> Directive[GrayLevel[0.7], Dashed]]
```

[image]

```
myTFM = TransferFunctionModel[bp[s], s]

TransferFunctionModel[{{{1000}}, (1 + Rational[1, 1000000] s) (1 + 
Rational[1, 1000] s)}, s]

bdP = BodePlot[myTFM, PlotLayout -> "Magnitude"]
```

[image]

```
Cases[Normal@bdP, Line[s_] :> s, Infinity]
```

> `{{{1.69897,59.9892},{1.70069,59.9891},{1.70241,59.989},{1.70584,59.9888},{1.71272,59.9884},{1.72646,59.9877},{1.72818,59.9876},{1.7299,59.9875},{1.73333,59.9873},{1.74021,59.9869},{1.75395,59.986},{1.75567,59.9859},{1.75739,59.9858},{1.76082,59.9856},{1.7677,59.9851},{1.78144,59.9842},{1.80893,59.982},{1.81079,59.9819},{1.81266,59.9817},{1.81638,59.9814},{1.82383,59.9807},{1.83873,59.9794},{1.8406,59.9792},{1.84246,59.979},{1.84618,59.9787},{1.85363,59.9779},{1.86854,59.9764},{1.8704,59.9762},{1.87226,59.976},{1.87599,59.9755},{1.88344,59.9747},{1.89834,59.9729},{1.92814,59.9689},{1.92988,59.9687},{1.93162,59.9684},{1.9351,59.9679},{1.94205,59.9669},{1.95597,59.9647},{1.95771,59.9644},{1.95945,59.9641},{1.96293,59.9635},{1.96988,59.9624},{1.9838,59.9599},{1.98554,59.9596},{1.98727,59.9592},{1.99075,59.9586},{1.99771,59.9572},{2.01162,59.9544},{2.03945,59.9482},{2.04116,59.9478},{2.04286,59.9474},{2.04627,59.9466},{2.05309,59.9449},{2.06673,59.9413},{2.06844,59.9409},{2.07014,59.9404},{2.07355,59.9395},{2.08037,59.9376},{2.09401,59.9336},{2.09572,59.933},{2.09742,59.9325},{2.10084,59.9314},{2.10766,59.9293},{2.1213,59.9247},{2.14858,59.9148},{2.15043,59.914},{2.15228,59.9133},{2.15598,59.9118},{2.16338,59.9088},{2.17817,59.9024},{2.18002,59.9016},{2.18187,59.9008},{2.18557,59.8991},{2.19297,59.8956},{2.20777,59.8884},{2.20962,59.8874},{2.21147,59.8865},{2.21516,59.8846},{2.22256,59.8806},{2.23736,59.8723},{2.26695,59.854},{2.26868,59.8528},{2.27041,59.8517},{2.27386,59.8494},{2.28076,59.8446},{2.29457,59.8346},{2.2963,59.8333},{2.29803,59.832},{2.30148,59.8293},{2.30838,59.8239},{2.32219,59.8126},{2.32392,59.8111},{2.32564,59.8097},{2.3291,59.8067},{2.336,59.8006},{2.34981,59.7878},{2.37743,59.7598},{2.3793,59.7578},{2.38117,59.7557},{2.38491,59.7516},{2.3924,59.7432},{2.40736,59.7254},{2.40923,59.7231},{2.4111,59.7208},{2.41484,59.7161},{2.42233,59.7065},{2.43729,59.6862},{2.43916,59.6836},{2.44103,59.681},{2.44478,59.6756},{2.45226,59.6647},{2.46722,59.6417},{2.49716,59.5912},{2.49899,59.5879},{2.50083,59.5846},{2.5045,59.5778},{2.51185,59.564},{2.52654,59.535},{2.52838,59.5313},{2.53021,59.5275},{2.53389,59.5199},{2.54123,59.5043},{2.55593,59.4716},{2.55776,59.4674},{2.5596,59.4631},{2.56327,59.4545},{2.57062,59.4369},{2.58531,59.4001},{2.6147,59.3197},{2.61641,59.3147},{2.61812,59.3097},{2.62155,59.2995},{2.6284,59.2788},{2.64211,59.2358},{2.66952,59.1425},{2.67123,59.1363},{2.67295,59.1301},{2.67637,59.1176},{2.68322,59.0921},{2.69693,59.039},{2.72434,58.9246},{2.7262,58.9164},{2.72806,58.9082},{2.73177,58.8915},{2.7392,58.8576},{2.75406,58.787},{2.78379,58.6345},{2.78564,58.6244},{2.7875,58.6143},{2.79122,58.5939},{2.79865,58.5523},{2.81351,58.4659},{2.84323,58.2804},{2.84497,58.269},{2.8467,58.2576},{2.85017,58.2345},{2.85711,58.1877},{2.87098,58.091},{2.89873,57.8854},{2.90046,57.872},{2.9022,57.8585},{2.90566,57.8314},{2.9126,57.7763},{2.92648,57.663},{2.95422,57.4234},{2.95592,57.4081},{2.95762,57.3928},{2.96102,57.362},{2.96782,57.2995},{2.98143,57.1715},{3.00863,56.9026},{3.06303,56.3138},{3.06488,56.2926},{3.06672,56.2714},{3.07041,56.2288},{3.07779,56.1425},{3.09255,55.9664},{3.12206,55.5998},{3.18109,54.8117},{3.29125,53.1661},{3.41065,51.1765},{3.52788,49.0763},{3.6372,47.0309},{3.75577,44.7527},{3.86645,42.5912},{3.98637,40.2262},{4.10411,37.8903},{4.21395,35.7037},{4.33304,33.3279},{4.44423,31.1065},{4.55323,28.9264},{4.67148,26.5588},{4.78184,24.3461},{4.90144,21.9429},{5.01886,19.5752},{5.12838,17.3543},{5.24715,14.9233},{5.35802,12.6192},{5.46671,10.3083},{5.58465,7.70886},{5.69468,5.15424},{5.81397,2.18383},{5.92535,-0.834754},{6.03456,-4.06071},{6.15301,-7.86465},{6.26356,-11.672},{6.38336,-16.0204},{6.50098,-20.4512},{6.61069,-24.6811},{6.72966,-29.3347},{6.84073,-33.7186},{6.94961,-38.0389},{7.06774,-42.7414},{7.17798,-47.1382},{7.1799,-47.2149},{7.18182,-47.2916},{7.18567,-47.4451},{7.19336,-47.7521},{7.20874,-48.3662},{7.2395,-49.5945},{7.24143,-49.6713},{7.24335,-49.7481},{7.24719,-49.9017},{7.25489,-50.2088},{7.27027,-50.8232},{7.27219,-50.9},{7.27411,-50.9768},{7.27796,-51.1304},{7.28565,-51.4376},{7.28757,-51.5144},{7.28949,-51.5912},{7.29334,-51.7448},{7.29526,-51.8216},{7.29718,-51.8984},{7.29911,-51.9752},{7.30103,-52.052}}}`

ListPlot[%]

[image]