# How to get coordinate of point from plots?

Tags: plotting, control-systems

I used BodePlot function to plot the magnitude and phase for a transfer function as below.

```
BodePlot[(1+s/10^6)/((1+s/10^2) (1+s/10^12)),{0.1,10^20}]
```

Now I want to do the following things:

1. Find the magnitude of the transfer function from the magnitude plot at 2*10^7 Hz.
2. Find the phase of the transfer function from the phase plot at 2*10^7 Hz.

Is there a way to get exact these numbers? I tried to use Getcoordinate () function from drawing tool and then move cursor to that point but I only get the approximated result.

[image]

Comment: Possible duplicate:  [How to get exact coordinate of a point from a plot?](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/115631/9490)

Answer (score 2):

*Update (answer simplified).*

Defining the function you're using as

```
t[s_] := (1 + s/10^6) / ( (1 + s/10^2) (1 + s/10^12) )
```

you can get the exact magnitude and phase at `2*10^7` Hertz from [`AbsArg`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/AbsArg.html):

```
AbsArg[t[I 2 10^7]]
(* {50000 Sqrt[401/100000000042500000001], -ArcTan[10003000001/199999850020]} *)
```

---

*Comments (based on old answer).*

While not necessary for the present question, you can be interested in defining a `FunctionTransferModel` for the function `t`:

```
tfm = TransferFunctionModel[t[s], s]
```

Different properties for the model can be given at construction time by specifying particular values for the options of `TransferFunctionModel`. Also, other symbols that act on `TransferFunctionModel` expressions can be used to access in a simple and direct way properties of the model, such as `TransferFunctionZeros` and `TransferFunctionPoles`.

With `tfm`, the exact magnitude and phase are obtained in a similar way:

```
AbsArg[tfm[I 2 10^7][[1, 1]]]
(* {50000 Sqrt[401/100000000042500000001], -ArcTan[10003000001/199999850020]} *)

% === AbsArg[t[I 2 10^7]]
(* True *)
```

Comment: Thanks a lot.
Could you explain what is the function of "TransferFunctionModel" here?
I read this from the help section of Mathematica:

TransferFunctionModel represents the model of the transfer-function matrix m with complex variable s.

But I don't see any difference between input and output of this function.

Also, tfm[I 2. 10^7][[1, 1]]: this is new to me too. Could you tell me where can I read more about this?

Comment: Thanks. What is the purpose of converting the expression into the form with  the top-right T?

Comment: Also why **I 2. 10^7** not just **2. 10^7**? Why should we include the imaginary variable **I** here?

Comment: Xavier: thanks a lot for the explanation and sorry for my lack of understanding. Could you tell me where can I read more about these things? Actually, I can't understand why we use TransferFunctionModel to convert something like 1/s into 1/s with the T-like letter on the top right.
What is the purpose of that? I don't see the difference between that expression (1/s) and the transfer function model (1/s with T on the top right). Also in **tfm[I f]** how do you know that we should put the imaginary I here?

Answer (score 0):

If you have the plots, you can simply use [`Cases`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Cases.html) to extract the datapoints being plotted, and [`Interpolation`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Interpolation.html), to create a functional form.

```
{magnitude, phase} = Interpolation /@ Cases[
   BodePlot[(1 + s/10^6)/((1 + s/10^2) (1 + s/10^12)), {0.1, 10^20}],
   Line[pts_] :> pts, Infinity]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

Notice that the domain is from {-1, 20}, which means that the inputs to these functions are actually the base-10 logarithm, so to get the values you just use

```
magnitude[Log10[2 10^7]]
phase[Log10[2 10^7]]
(* -79.9892 *)
(* -2.86327 *)
```

These correspond to the values shown in the plot.