# ContourStyle for a particular contour line in ContourPlot

Tags: plotting

I have the following command:

```
ContourPlot[(-1 + x)^2 (-1 + y) + x^2 y,
{x, 0, 1}, {y, 0, 1},
ContourLabels -> True]
```

which gives me

[image]

I want to highlight the 0-contour line, e.g. make it thicker, dashed, red, etc., but *Mathematica*'s documentation on `ContourPlot` does not seem to provide a way to specify the style for particular contour lines.

How should I specify the style for particular contour lines?

Comment: I do not know how to make it automatic and apply style to only one but it is the way you can go: `Contours -> (Table[i, {i, -.8, .8, .2}]~Join~{{0, Directive[Thick, Red]}})`

Comment: Or even `Contours -> (If[# == 0, {0, Directive[Thick, Dashed, Red]}, #] & /@ 
   Range[-.8, .8, .2])` so it doesn't draw the 0-contour line twice.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Here is another very simple way to modify a particular contour. You just have to turn on `Tooltip` labeling, and then pick out the line with the tooltip `0` to modify its graphics `Directive` using a replacement rule. First I define a new style for the contour, then I apply it:

```
newStyle[x_] := x /. l_Line :> Sequence[
    Opacity[.4], Thick, Dashed, Red,
    l
    ]

ContourPlot[(-1 + x)^2 (-1 + y) + x^2 y, {x, 0, 1}, {y, 0, 1}, 
  ContourLabels -> All] /. Tooltip[x_, 0] :> Tooltip[newStyle[x], 0]
```

[image: red contour]

To make `Tooltip` appear in *addition* to contour labels, I used `ContourLabels -> All`.

**Edit**

Thanks to MichaelE2's comment, I addressed the case where you also want to style the other contour lines, but just add a different style for the particular contour `0`.

All the style modifications are done in the function `newStyle`, which inserts the additional directives in front of the contour line. This allows pre-existing definitions from the `ContourStyle` option to coexist with the new directives.

**Edit 2 in response to comment**

One general problem with `ContourLabels` is that their automatic placement is incredibly clumsy most of the time. You can see this in the above example, where the labels are scrunched up against the frame for no good reason. Giving your labels additional pretty styling such as frames and backgrounds is kind of futile if their placement looks so bad.

Therefore, in practice I would argue it's inevitable that you'll want to place the labels manually. And if you do it that way, then my favorite approach is to use tha answer I gave [here](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/9187/245).

- Copy the definition for `burnTooltip` (including its `Options`)
- Define the same `ContourPlot` as before, but with `ContourLabels -> Automatic` so that *only* `Tooltip` is used.
- Execute `burnToltip` with the desired option for `"LabelFunction"` (e.g. to get a frame)
- Click to place the contour labels anywhere you want
- **Finish by right-clicking** on the plot. Then you can copy or export it as a `Graphics` object.

Here is the code:

```
c = ContourPlot[(-1 + x)^2 (-1 + y) + x^2 y, {x, 0, 1}, {y, 0, 1}, 
    ContourLabels -> Automatic] /. 
   Tooltip[x_, 0] :> Tooltip[newStyle[x], 0];

burnTooltips[c, "LabelFunction" -> (Framed[#, Background -> White] &)]
```

[image: burned]

This is the result I got. Now the contour is styled as desired, *and* you got labels in reasonable-looking positions.

Comment: +1 Nice and neat.  But note it only seems to work for the default `ContourStyle -> Automatic` and does not override an explicit setting.  To do that, one might use something like `Tooltip[x_, 0] :> Tooltip[x /. l_Line :> {Opacity[.4], Thick, Dashed, Red, l}, 0]`.

Comment: @MichaelE2 Thanks - I'll edit when I have time to try it out...

Comment: How should I turn on tooltip if my `ContourLabels` option is set to `ContourLabels -> (Text[Framed[#3], {#1, #2}, Background -> White] &)`?

Comment: @wdg In that case see my new edit.

Comment: Hi, I tried your example but strangely the contour labels are not shown. I am using MM 10.4

Comment: @yangyang If you mean the `burnTooltips1 method, you have to first click on the contours.

Comment: @Jens Ah, sorry I didn't see your last comment. This is very nice. Thanks a lot!!!

Answer (score 5):

There is way to style individual [`Contour`](http://reference.wolfram.com/mathematica/ref/Contour.html)s:

> `{{f1, gr1},...}`   contours drawn with graphics directives `gri`

and a way to have a function compute the contours for you:

> `func`        a function to be applied to `zmin`, `zmax` to get the list of contours

Unfortunately they do not seem to cooperate -- that is, if `func` returns a list of contour levels and graphics directives `{{f1, gr1},...}`, all I get is a gray square for the plot.  No error warnings, no contours.  If this is by design, it seems that it leaves room for improvement.

However, one can take a two-step approach.  Below is a function that does one contour plot to compute the list of styled contours and another to compute the image.  To improve speed, by default, `MaxRecursion` is set to `0`; this can be overridden.  All we really need to know to compute the contours is the maximum and minimum of the plotted function over the domain.  There are various ways to compute this. `ContourPlot` is one.  Sometimes human inspection is quick enough.  If I can assume quality is more important than speed, then a double `ContourPlot` is reasonable.

I made a some attempt to provide an interface with `ContourPlot`, but the variety of forms of the options, especially `Contours` and `ContourStyle`, and my limited time led to a partial implementation.

The function `cFn` yields a `Function` that computes the styled contours.  Each contour has to be styled with this form of the option `Contours`.  I apply the `ContourStyle` `cStyle`, which needs to be a single style, to the union of the user-styled and the automatically generated contours.  The styles of the user-styled contours are then replaced by the styles the user specifies.  The integer `nContours` represents the "target" number of contours to be returned by `FindDivisions`; it won't be the exact number of contours due to the workings of `FindDivisions`.

If the max/min of the function are known, then `contours = cFn[styledContours][min, max]` may be used to compute the value for the option `Contours -> contours` directly.

To use `cplot`, just pass a list of contours in the form `{{f1, gr1},...}`, the same as for the option `Contours`, followed by the arguments for `ContourPlot`.

```
Clear[cFn];
cFn[styledContours_, nContours_: 10, cStyle_: {GrayLevel[0], Opacity[0.4]}] /; 
  ArrayDepth[styledContours] == 1 := cFn[{styledContours}, nContours];
cFn[styledContours_, nContours_: 10, cStyle_: {GrayLevel[0], Opacity[0.4]}] := 
  Function[{min, max}, {#, cStyle} & /@ 
      Union[First /@ N@styledContours, N @ FindDivisions[{min, max}, nContours]] /. 
     Thread[{#, cStyle} & /@ First /@ N @ styledContours -> styledContours]];

ClearAll[cplot];
SetAttributes[cplot, HoldAll];
cplot[styledContours_, fn_, dom1_, dom2_, opts : OptionsPattern[ContourPlot]] :=
 Module[{contours},
  ContourPlot[fn, dom1, dom2, PlotPoints -> OptionValue[PlotPoints], 
   MaxRecursion -> 
    If[OptionValue[MaxRecursion] === Automatic, 0, OptionValue[MaxRecursion]], 
   Contours -> ((contours = cFn[styledContours, 
                  If[IntegerQ[OptionValue[Contours]], IntegerQ[OptionValue[Contours]], 10], 
                  OptionValue[ContourStyle]][##]) &)];
  ContourPlot[fn, dom1, dom2, Contours -> contours, opts]
  ]
```

Example

```
cplot[{0, {Thick, Red}}, (-1 + x)^2 (-1 + y) + x^2 y,
 {x, 0, 1}, {y, 0, 1}, ContourLabels -> True]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

I hope that helps.  If `Contours -> func` ever works the way I think it should, this would be a bit easier.

Answer (score 3):

You can specify a style for individual contour lines by using `Contours->{ { contour value, graphics directive }, … }`.

```
ContourPlot[
  (-1 + x)^2 * (-1 + y) + x^2 * y,
  { x, 0, 1 },
  { y, 0, 1 },
  ContourLabels->True,
  Contours->(
    (* Create a list of { contour value, graphics directive } pairs.
     * If a graphics directive is Null, it will have the default
     * contour line style. *)
    {
      #,
      If[# == 0,
        Directive[ Thick, Dashed, Red ],
        Null (* Replace this if you want to change the default
              * contour graphics directives. *)
      ]
    }& /@ Range[ -10, 10, 0.2 ]
  )
]
```

[image: Result]

This does not work with `Contours->Automatic`, so you'll need to specify your contour values manually. The example above uses `Range` to specify the contour values.

Comment: Well, this is Kuba's and Rahul's comments merged into one ... @glyph

Comment: @Sektor: Thanks for pointing that out, I can't believe I didn't notice Rahul's comment when studying this page. It would have saved me some time. I think it is the simplest and most general solution to the question asked and I tried to present it in the clearest way possible with comments; it deserves its own answer.

Comment: To improve this answer `Range` could be automated. Not sure if that is possible in a clean and general way.