# How to color a particular contour line in a ContourPlot and obtain the area surrounded?

Tags: plotting, numerical-integration

I want to

$1.$ highlight a contour line in a `ContourPlot` by coloring it, and

$2.$ obtain the area surrounded by that contour line.

For example, I want to color the contour of $-0.72$ in the following figure to red, then obtain the area of the inner part of the contour of $-0.72$.

$Note:$

$1.$ I am looking for a general method because in my real problem the object *function* (here `Cos[x] + Cos[y]`) was obtained numerically as an `InterpolatingFunction`, and

$2.$ the region of interest surrounded by the contour line is an irregular region.

```
ContourPlot[Cos[x] + Cos[y], {x, 0, 4 Pi}, {y, 0, 4 Pi}, 
Contours -> 10, ContourStyle -> {AbsoluteThickness[1], Black}, 
PlotLegends -> Automatic]
```

[image]

Thank you!

Comment: I would `b = ContourPlot[{Cos[x] + Cos[y] == -0.72}, {x, 0, 4 Pi}, {y, 0, 
   4 Pi}, ContourStyle -> {AbsoluteThickness[5], Red}]` and `Show[a,b]` it together with your plot `a`.

Comment: What if the contour you want to highlight is not there? E.g. `-0.9` is not marked there but have you known before plotting? Do you want to force it to be created? How should it work with `Contours` spec you use.

Comment: @Kuba, in general, I will plot it using black color with specified number for `Contours` and determine which contour I'd like to highlight :) then I will use a certain trick to color it to red.

Comment: @jsxs Unrelated question but, are you by any chance working with acoustic fields?

Comment: @Keine, sorry, I am not working with acoustic fields.

Comment: Related: http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/28762/contourstyle-for-a-particular-contour-line-in-contourplot

Comment: Hi @MichaelE2, thanks for this useful link!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Single out one contour:

```
ContourPlot[Cos[x] + Cos[y] == 0.72, {x, 0, 4 Pi}, {y, 0, 4 Pi}, ContourStyle -> Red]
```

[image]

Use `Show` to combine several graphics outputs.

By visually inspecting the result, we can determine a bounding box for the contour in the middle: it is $([\pi,3\pi], [\pi, 3\pi])$.

Comparing with your original contour plot, we see that the enclosed region is defined by the equation `Cos[x] + Cos[y] > 0.72`.  In other cases we might need to use `<` instead.

Define it as a region (version 10 and later):

```
reg = ImplicitRegion[Cos[x] + Cos[y] > 0.72, {{x, Pi, 3 Pi}, {y, Pi, 3 Pi}}];
```

Find the area: `Area[reg]`.  Also look up `RegionMeasure`.

Plot it: `RegionPlot[reg]`

In versions before 10, find the area:

```
NIntegrate[Boole[Cos[x] + Cos[y] > 0.72], {x, Pi, 3 Pi}, {y, Pi, 3 Pi}]
```

Plot it:

```
RegionPlot[Cos[x] + Cos[y] > 0.72, {x, Pi, 3 Pi}, {y, Pi, 3 Pi}]
```