# How do I add contour labels to contour plot?

Tags: plotting

I tried

```
ContourPlot[f[x, y], {x, -2, 2}, {y, -2, 2}, ContourLabels->automatic]
```

, but it messes up the contourplot. How can I just add values to the contours for

```
ContourPlot[f[x, y], {x, -2, 2}, {y, -2, 2}]
```

?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Looking at the rather dismal automatic placement of contour labels in the example `Sin[x y]`, I thought it may be worth pointing out that you can often get better results with customized placement.

For this, I devised a function `burnTooltip` in [this answer](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/9187/245). Here is how to use it for this question:

```
Options[burnTooltips] = {ImageSize -> 360, 
   "LabelFunction" -> (Framed[#, FrameStyle -> None, 
       RoundingRadius -> 8, Background -> RGBColor[1, .8, .4]] &)};

burnTooltips[plot_, opt : OptionsPattern[]] := 
 DynamicModule[{ins = {}, wrapper = OptionValue["LabelFunction"], 
   toolRule = 
    Function[{arg}, 
     Tooltip[t__] :> 
      Button[Tooltip[t], 
       AppendTo[arg, 
        Inset[wrapper[Last[{t}]], MousePosition["Graphics"]]]], 
     HoldAll]}, 
  EventHandler[
   Dynamic@Show[plot /. toolRule[ins], Graphics@ins, 
     ImageSize -> OptionValue[ImageSize]], {"MouseUp", 
     2} :> (toolRule = {} &)]]

f[x_, y_] := Sin[x y]
p = ContourPlot[f[x, y], {x, -2, 2}, {y, -2, 2}, 
   ContourLabels -> Automatic];

burnTooltips[p]
```

[image: tooltipburned]

When you execute the last line, the plot appears and tooltips will be shown when you hover over the contours. If you see a tooltip in a location that you like, click the mouse. Repeat this for as many labels as you need. Every time you click, a new label will be added permanently at the mouse position. When you're **done**, you have to **right-click** on the plot. That will end the dynamic interactivity and burn the existing labels in place.

Answer (score 4):

```
f[x_, y_] := Sin[x y]
ContourPlot[f[x, y], {x, -2, 2}, {y, -2, 2}, ContourLabels -> All]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

Or if you want only some of them:

```
f[x_, y_] := Sin[x y]
ContourPlot[f[x, y], {x, -2, 2}, {y, -2, 2}, 
            ContourLabels -> (If[Abs@#3 <= .25, Text[#3, {#1, #2}]] &)]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]