# assign different values to the function of ContourPlot

Tags: plotting

I have a H function which describe the location of the same temperature. I can draw the function with ContourPlot. But the real value of the temperature needed to be calculated separately. I need to plot the temperature on the Contour. How should I assign the value to the ContourPlot?

Comment: Uh :D ? `ListContourPlot` ? Otherwise add more details and try to clarify what exactly you need.

Comment: For custom labels see this nice [post](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/66433/how-do-i-add-contour-labels-to-contour-plot/66439#66439).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[`ContourLabels`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/ContourLabels.html) displaying any quantity you wish can be created with an option of the sort, `ContourLabels -> (Text[Framed[#3^2], {#1, #2}, Background -> White] &)`.  In this case, it creates labels displaying the square of the contour value, but `#3^2` can be replaced by any desired expression involving `#3`, the value of the plotted function.  For instance, the `ContourPlot` produced by

```
ContourPlot[Sin[x - y], {x, 0, Pi}, {y, 0, Pi}, 
 ContourLabels -> (Text[Framed[#3^2], {#1, #2}, Background -> White] &)]
```

is

[image: Sample plot]