# How can I customize the tooltips on a ContourPlot?

Tags: plotting, tooltip

I have a contour plot and I would like to have finer control over the tooltips that are displayed.

For the sake of argument, suppose that I have the following plot,

```
ContourPlot[
 Exp[-x^2 - y^2]
 , {x, 0, 2}, {y, 0, 2}
 , PlotRange -> Full
 , Contours -> 10^Range[-4, 0, 0.1]
 ]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

and I would like to force scientific notation on the tooltips - say, I'd like every tooltip in the form $10^{-3.7}$. More generally, I would like to apply a user-supplied function `tooltipFunction` to the value `F[x,y]` of the plotted function at the contour and display this as the tooltip.

The documentation for [`ContourLabels`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/ContourLabels.html) hints that this should be possible, via a specification of the form

> `ContourLabels->{f,g}` uses `f[x,y,z]` as an explicit displayed label, and uses `g[x,y,z]` as a tooltip for each complete contour line.

However, there are no examples on the documentation and naive implementations of this don't seem to work.

Is there any way to implement this, preferably within the confines of the ContourPlot call?

Answer (score 5):

Here is what I think is going on with the second argument to `ContourLabel`.

Everything starts with the fact that `ContourPlot` has `Attribute` of `HoldAll`, which means that all the options you give it can be parsed in a *non-standard* way before being evaluated.

This seems to be happening in the `ContourLabels` option: it is scanned for the appearance of `Tooltip`, and apparently also for a slot `#2`. But **all other slots such as** `#1` or `#3`  **are unused.** In other words, the first argument of `Tooltip` in the `ContourLabel` option could equally be replaced by `#` or `Null` or `blah`, because the held form of `Tooltip` that is given in the option is parsed in such a way that its first argument is *always* taken as the slot into which the contour line is later inserted, no matter what you put in at the time when you specify it as an option.

To see that `ContourPlot` parses its `ContourLabel` option in this non-standard way, one can try this:

```
Clear[blah];
ContourPlot[Exp[-x^2 - y^2], {x, 0, 2}, {y, 0, 2}, PlotRange -> Full, 
 Contours -> 10^Range[-4, 0, 0.1], 
 ContourLabels -> {None, 
   Tooltip[blah, DisplayForm[SuperscriptBox[10, Log[10, #2]]]] &}]
```

[image: tooltip]

So the content of the first argument to `Tooltip` is simply discarded when provided as an option in `ContourPlot`, and only `#2` has any meaning.

This non-standard parsing of the held expression would also explain why you cannot obtain the same result by specifying

```
labelFunction = Function[{x, y},
   Tooltip[x, DisplayForm[SuperscriptBox[10, Log[10, y]]]]];
```

and then using the option

```
ContourLabels -> {None, labelFunction}
```

in `ContourPlot`. There is no literal `Tooltip` appearing in the held expression passed as an option, and as a result *Mathematica* doesn't plot any contour tooltips with this approach, despite the fact that `Function` would normally be an admissible replacement for the `&` construct that was used above.

Comment: Oh, OK - the `HoldAll` argument makes sense. Bizarre choice of syntax, overall, on multiple counts.

Comment: Thank you for chiming in on this. I am still a bit confused as to how the innards of ContourPlot check for the *literal* presence of Tooltip. `Head[expression] == Tooltip`?

Answer (score 4):

Hat-tip to [DrMajorBob](https://groups.google.com/d/msg/comp.soft-sys.math.mathematica/rZ8n1xehF9U/gkvsmp0hsMoJ) for this handy workaround:

```
ContourPlot[
  Exp[-x^2 - y^2]
  , {x, 0, 2}, {y, 0, 2}
  , PlotRange -> Full
  , Contours -> 10^Range[-4, 0, 0.1]
  ] /. {Tooltip[expr_, tooltip_] :> Tooltip[expr, 
         DisplayForm[SuperscriptBox[10, Log[10, tooltip]]]
     ]}
```

This uses the fact that `Tooltip`'d expressions have a very distinctive form, and therefore make very easy targets for the pattern matcher.

More generally, the replacement rule

```
/. {Tooltip[expr_, tooltip_] :> Tooltip[expr, tooltipFunction[tooltip]]}
```

will apply `tooltipFunction` to the label of any `Tooltip` in the expression to its left.

However, it would still be nice to have some insight into how `ContourLabels` is meant to work in this context.

Comment: There's a `Log10[]` function, but `MantissaExponent[]` might be a better choice here.

Comment: @Guesswhoitis. I'm not interested so much in the actual handling of `tooltip` by that replacement rule as in understanding how I can deploy a `tooltipFunction` to change its value.

Comment: I know. :) Since you mentioned scientific notation, I just made a note on how to construct it. (I'll upvote when I can again.)

Comment: In this specific case it was intentional - this form makes the log scale much easier to parse. For full scientific notation, I know there are better tools `;)`.

Answer (score 4):

The solution below seems to work for me from within `ContourPlot`, using the `ContourLabels` option:

```
ContourPlot[
 Exp[-x^2 - y^2],
 {x, 0, 2}, {y, 0, 2},
 PlotRange -> Full,
 Contours -> 10^Range[-4, 0, 0.1],
 ContourLabels -> {None, Tooltip[#3, DisplayForm[SuperscriptBox[10, Log[10, #2]]]] &}
]
```

[image: Plot with custom contour tooltips]

The key piece of information is the fact that the `g` function referred to in the documentation to `ContourLabels` must *itself* be a `Tooltip` function, and *not* an argument for Tooltip as the documentation seems to suggest. I stumbled across this nugget some time ago in an excellent [answer by Jens](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/9187/27951) on this site.

Comment: Huh. Can you comment on arguments are given to `g`? The obvious diagnosis is `ContourLabels -> {None, Tooltip[#3, {#1, #2, #3}] &}` but it produces tooltips of the form `{#1, 0.125893, #3}`, which completely stumps me. How can `#2` return something while `#1` doesn't? Since `#3` does not return anything, does it matter what's in the first argument of `g`'s `Tooltip` call? No wonder this had people stumped.

Comment: @episanty Unfortunately, that part baffles me as well. Essentially, I used trial-and-error to choose the argument to `g`. The documentation is impressively unhelpful on this point. My best guess at this point is that `g` may be passed the *contour line itself* as #3, and the contour value as #2, so not $(x,y,z)$ values as suggested by the docs, but I still don't know for sure!

Comment: From what I can tell, (i) `g` is only passed the value of the contour, as its *second* argument, and (ii) the first `Tooltip` argument is never touched. It seems this can be anything and the tooltips will display. For an interesting twist, try `ContourLabels -> {None, Tooltip[Print["bingo"], {#1, #2, #3}] &}`. Moreover, neither of `ContourLabels -> {None, Tooltip[, {##}] &}` or `ContourLabels -> {None, Tooltip[, {##2}] &}` produce anything sensible. Bizarre.

Comment: @episanty Yes, I was also trying to "catch" the value of the parameters passed to `g` with `Print`, but I could make no sense of that particular effort.

Comment: @episanty I added an answer to explain what I believe is going on.