# Adding contour labels in regular plots

Tags: plotting

How can "`ContourLabels`" be added into regular curves given by `Plot` or `ListLinePlot`?

Note: It is also important to comfortably control the location, density and alignment of the labels.

For example:

```
ListLinePlot[Table[Table[i^j, {i,0,5,.1}],{j,1,3}],PlotRange->{0, 10}]
```

gives:

[image]

How can it be plotted as:

[image]

Comment: ListLinePlot[Table[Table[{i, i^j}, {i, 0, 5, .1}], {j, 1, 3}], 
 PlotRange -> {0, All}, 
 PlotLabels -> {Placed[Text["j=1", Background -> White], {4, 4}], 
   Placed[Text["j=2", Background -> White], {4, 4^2}], 
   Placed[Text["j=3", Background -> White], {4, 4^3}]}]

This could be a starting point

Comment: You can simply use the function `burnTooltip` from [my answer here](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/9187/245), if you generate your plot as (in the notation of that answer)  `toolPlot = ListLinePlot[
  Table[Tooltip[Table[i^j, {i, 0, 5, .1}], 
    Row[{"j \[LongEqual] ", j}]], {j, 1, 3}], PlotRange -> {0, 10}]`. Although that [linked question](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/9182/245) was about `ContourPlot`, my answer works for any plot. It may also be worth mentioning `Callout` as another option.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

From the manual of `Plot`:

> The following wrappers can be used for the plotted function `f`:
>
> > - `Labeled[f,label]` -   label the function
> > - `Labeled[f,label,pos]` -place the label at relative position pos

```
Plot[
 Evaluate@Table[
   Labeled[i^j, StringTemplate["j=``"][j], 5 - j/2],
   {j, 1, 3}
   ],
 {i, 0, 5}]
```

[image]

Mathmatica takes care of the placement for you, but using the third argument of `Labeled` you can override it the way you want. The acceptet format for the postition argument is given in the manual for `Plot`. The best are perhaps `Above`, `Below`, `Before` and `After`, which remove any need for manual position adjustment.

I took liberty to implement the same figure with `Plot` instead of `ListPlot`  as I find it more elegent to leave the proper sampling to Mathematica. However, the same wrappers are also supported by `ListPlot` if you should need.

**Edit**
I guess the rotation of the label is not very important, but just for the heck of it I also wanted to propose a way it could be done:

```
dataAspectRatio = 20
labelf[f_, label_, arg_, labelArg_] := 
 Labeled[f[arg], 
  Rotate[Style[label, Background -> White], 
   ArcTan[D[f[x], x]/dataAspectRatio /. x -> labelArg]], {labelArg, 
   f[labelArg]}]
Plot[
 Evaluate@Table[
   labelf[#^j &, StringTemplate["j=``"][j], i, 5 - j/2],
   {j, 1, 3}
   ],
 {i, 0, 5}]
```

[image]

Note, that white background can be removed by removing `Background -> White`.

Answer (score 2):

Try this:

```
points = {};

Manipulate[DynamicModule[{pts = {{10, 2}, {20, 4}, {30, 6}}},
  Column[{
    LocatorPane[Dynamic[pts],

     Dynamic@
      ListLinePlot[Table[Table[i^j, {i, 0, 5, .1}], {j, 1, 3}], 
       PlotRange -> {0, 10}, ImageSize -> 300,
       Epilog -> {Inset[
          Rotate[Panel[Style["j=1", Italic, 18], 
            Background -> White], \[Alpha]], pts[[1]]],
         Inset[
          Rotate[Panel[Style["j=2", Italic, 18], 
            Background -> White], \[Beta]], pts[[2]]],
         Inset[
          Rotate[Panel[Style["j=3", Italic, 18], 
            Background -> White], \[Gamma]], pts[[3]]]
                        }
                                                  ]
      ],

    Button["Copy the list of points", Clear[points]; points = pts; 
     Print[points]]

             }]

  ], {\[Alpha], 0, \[Pi]}, {\[Beta], 0, \[Pi]}, {\[Gamma], 0, \[Pi]}]
```

yielding the following

[image]

You act as follows:

1. With locators position the labels on their places.
2. With sliders adjust the angles of the labels
3. Press the button and a set of points will appear below the panel. Pick up the points and insert them under the ListLinePlot statement instead of pts[[1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/kpWEz.jpg)],pts[[2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/d337l.jpg)] and pts[[3]].
4. By clicking on the Animation Control Box (containing the sign "+") open the controls, pick up the values of alpha, beta and gamma and insert them under the ListLinePlot statement.
5. Copy-paste the ListLinePlot statement in another place.

ListLinePlot[Table[Table[i^j, {i, 0, 5, .1}], {j, 1, 3}], PlotRange -> {0, 10}, ImageSize -> 300, Epilog -> {
Inset[Rotate[Panel[Style["j=1", Italic, 18], Background -> White], 
     0.383274], {31.95`, 3.24`}],
   Inset[Rotate[Panel[Style["j=2", Italic, 18], Background -> White], 
     1.04929], {28.15, 7.62`}],
   Inset[Rotate[Panel[Style["j=3", Italic, 18], Background -> White], 
     1.31004], {19.65, 7.02}]
                  }]

You will see this:

[image]

Done. Have fun!

Comment: This is very cool, definitely far from my abilities. However,  there are many problems, the white panels for example, do not fit when there are dense contours, and in general the whole process is time consuming.

Comment: @jarhead That's exactly what you demanded. You should formulate your requirements more precisely.