# How to place labels of many curves in good positions?

Tags: plotting, functions, function-construction, labeling

Would it be possible to put labels like this for all curves from 1 to 19? 
 It would also be nice if there are some way to put/adjust the position of labels manually for better positions.

```
myfunctions = {Abs[1 - 2 x], 3 - Abs[x], 1 - Abs[x]/3, 1 + x^2, 
   x^3 - 1, 5 - 2 Abs[x]/3, 1 + x, 1 - 2 x/3, 5 - x, 2 x - 5, 8 x - 5,
    1 - x - x^2, 2 - x/5, 5 - x, 3 - x^2, 6 - x^5/5, 2 + 3 x, 5 - E^x,
    ConditionalExpression[2, -3 <= x <= 1]};
Plot[myfunctions, {x, -5, 5}, PlotRange -> {Automatic, {0, 5}}, 
 GridLines -> Automatic, Frame -> True
```

[image]

I tried `PlotLabels -> Range[19]` but the labels'positions are not good and hard to read.

```
Plot[myfunctions, {x, -5, 5}, PlotRange -> {Automatic, {0, 5}}, 
 GridLines -> Automatic, Frame -> True, PlotLabels -> Range[19]]
```

[image]

Comment: See also [Custom contour labels in ContourPlot](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/9182/245)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

[image]

An alternative approach: To avoid adding additional clutter with callout lines to an already crowded plot, we can place labels *on* the curves and interactively adjust the label positions using `LocatorPane`:

First construct a plot with `Tooltips`:

```
plot = Plot[Evaluate[MapIndexed[Tooltip[#, First@#2] &, myfunctions]], {x, -5,  5}, 
  ImageSize -> Large, PlotRange -> {Automatic, {0, 5}}, 
  GridLines -> Automatic, Frame -> True]
```

[image]

```
lines = Cases[plot, {_Directive, l__Line} :> RegionUnion[l], All];
n = Length @ lines;
pos0 = RandomPoint /@ lines;
rNFs = RegionNearest /@ lines;

DynamicModule[{pts = pos0}, 
 LocatorPane[
  Dynamic[pts, (Do[pts[[i]] = rNFs[[i]] @ #[[i]], {i, 1, n}])&],
  Dynamic[Show[plot, 
    plot /. Tooltip[{d___, __Line}, tip_] :> Tooltip[{d, Disk[pts[[tip]], Offset[10]], 
     {White, Disk[pts[[tip]], Offset[8]]}, Text[Style[tip, 12], pts[[tip]]]}, tip]]], 
  Appearance -> None]]
```

[image]

After interactive adjustments we get the picture above.

**Note:** I sure hope you are not dealing with this kind of plots too often:)

Comment: That's very nice. Would it be possible to limit the movement of each label on the its responding curve only? The problem is that sometimes I don't know which curve and which corresponding label it belongs to and move the wrong place. Also the curves also move when I select it which is undesied as well.

Comment: @hana,each label is already restricted to stay on the curve it belongs to (this is done by the second argument in `Dynamic[pts, (Do[...])&)]`).

Comment: I'm sorry I probably checked the wrong code. It works perfectly. The only problem is somehow the curve and label's color doesn't match on my different example but I think I can solve it.

Comment: I wonder if you could help me test this example `myfunctions = {ConditionalExpression[Abs[1 - 2 x], x >= 1 || x <= 0], 
  ConditionalExpression[1 + x, x >= 0]}`. The colors of curves and labels don't match. I think the problem is probably that the first function has two branches. Here is the image showing the problem. 
https://ibb.co/6XWK1PZ

Comment: @hana, you are right about the source of the problem. I will update with a fix.

Comment: @hana, please try the updated version.

Comment: Thanks, it works well now. I tried modify last night but didn't make it.

Answer (score 7):

You may use [`Callout`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Callout.html) to explicitly set a location along the curve for the label.

Below I use [`Scaled`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Scaled.html) to set the label at the start or end of the curve.  Since the curves have varying start and end points this produces a spaced out labels.

With `myfunctions` in OP.

```
Plot[
 Evaluate[
  MapIndexed[
   Callout[#, First@#2, Scaled@Mod[First@#2, 2]] &
   , myfunctions
   ]
  ]
 , {x, -5, 5}
 , PlotRange -> {Automatic, {0, 5}}
 , GridLines -> Automatic
 , Frame -> True
 ]
```

> [image: Mathematica graphics]

[`Evaluate`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Evaluate.html) is needed to evaluate [`MapIndexed`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/MapIndexed.html) before the expression is passed to [`Plot`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Plot.html) because `Plot` has [`Attributes`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Attributes.html) [`HoldAll`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/HoldAll.html).

Hope this helps.

Comment: Thanks, I added `CalloutMarker -> "Circle"` to make it more clear to distinguish between lines. Would it be possible to change the some properties of these callouts such as color, bold to make it a bit more clear? Almost all callout looks good after adding `CalloutMarker -> "Circle"` but the numbers `10, 14, 19` are a bit confusing.

Comment: Try `MapIndexed[Callout[#, Style[First@#2, 12, Bold, ColorData[97][First@#2]], 
   Scaled@Mod[First@#2, 2], Appearance -> "Frame"] &, myfunctions]` and `PlotStyle -> ColorData[97]`.

Comment: @RohitNamjoshi that doesn't really solve the problem I mentioned above. I probably should do it manually for each curve.

Answer (score 5):

```
plot = Plot[Evaluate[MapIndexed[Tooltip[#, First@#2] &, myfunctions]], {x, -5,  5}, 
  ImageSize -> Large, PlotRange -> {Automatic, {0, 5}}, 
  GridLines -> Automatic, Frame -> True];
```

A simpler alternative to put labels *on* the curves:

Post-process `plot` to construct a label object (disks and a text label wrapped in `GraphicsGroup`) for each line. Then double-click the output to move the label objects to desired locations.

```
SeedRandom[1]
pos0 = RandomPoint /@ Cases[plot, _Line, All];

Show[plot, 
 plot /. Tooltip[{d___, _Line}, tip_] :> Tooltip[GraphicsGroup @ 
     {d, Disk[pos0[[tip]], Offset[10]], {White, Disk[pos0[[tip]], Offset[8]]}, 
      Text[Style[tip, 12], pos0[[tip]]]}, tip]]
```

[image]

Double-click on the output and drag the labels to desired locations:

[image]